# Syntax for checkboxes in extension

Tags: add-on-development, extension, checkbox

I’m creating a custom ExpressionEngine extension and I need to add a checkbox. I’m struggling to find the options I need to use for the channel fields API.

Currently I have:

```
array(
    'field_name' => 'business_for_sale',
    'field_label' => 'Business For Sale?',
    'field_type' => 'checkboxes',
    'field_order' => 25,
    'field_instructions' => 'Is there a business for sale with the commerical property?',
    'field_required' => 'n',
    'field_search' => 'y',
    'field_is_hidden' => 'n',
    'field_list_items' => "Yes",
)
```

I just want either a single checkbox that will act as a boolean (checked is yes, un-checked is no). Alternatively, I would settle for two radios buttons—one representing Yes and one representing No that the administrator could choose.

Comment: Are you creating an extension, or a fieldtype?

Comment: I’m creating an extension that on activation should create some channel fields, one of which I want to represent a boolean value (“yes” or “no”).

Answer (score 0):

Native EE checkbox fields simply store the options as plain text - to my knowledge there is no way to make one a *true* boolean. But what you have should work. The box being left unchecked will result in a NULL value for that field.

So all these should work.

```
{if business_for_sale == 'Yes'}
{if business_for_sale}
{if business_for_sale == ''}
```